# How can i delete a blank line PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this lines so i need delete blank line:

```
Fichier TESTTT 

testt have that
```

I've used `str_replace('\r\n','',$text);` but always I have this line blank
Thanks in advance

Comment: `str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n', '\r', '\n\r'), '', $text);`

Comment: this would reduce the complete text to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string);
```

Comment: Regex is overkill for this (more overhead than `str_replace`)

Comment: replacing two or more successive whitespace character with a blank? I don't think this is the intended result.

Comment: so i need juste delete the blank line and delete the white space under the first line

Comment: @paranoid Thanks for your answer i  will test that

Comment: If work corectly . vote and accept my post